# Questions on surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z_3[x]} \rightarrow \frac{\mathbb{Z_3[x]}}{(x^3 + x + 1)}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Say I define a homomorphism

$$\lambda : \mathbb{Z_3[x]} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_3[x]}/(x^3 + x + 1)$$
such that
$$\lambda(z) = \overline{z}$$

Then if I take the element $x^5 + 2x^2 +1$ in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$ and apply $\lambda$ to it I get -

$\lambda(x^5 + 2x^2 +1) = \overline{x^5 + 2x^2 +1}$

= $x^2 + x + 2$

...Because $x^5 + 2x^2 +1 = (x^3 + x + 1)(x^2 + 1) + (x^2 + x + 2)$

**Is that correct?**

Now based on the fact that $\lambda$ is a surjective homomorphism, there will be a bijection between the ideals in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}/(x^3 + x + 1)$ and the ideals in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$ containing $ker(\lambda)$.

Now $ker(\lambda) = (x^3 + x + 1)$

So the ideals in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}/(x^3 + x + 1)$ correspond to the ideals in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$ containing $(x^3 + x + 1)$.

**Is all that correct?**

Comment: do you mean to write $\mathbb Z_3[x]$ instead of $\mathbb Z_3$?

Comment: Yes, $$ \frac{\mathbb{Z_3}}{(x^3 + x + 1)}$$ is very confusing. Do you mean $$\mathbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle?$$ Using fraction notation is wrong here - there is no division happening.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it now.

Comment: Yes, it all seems correct, assuming $\;\overline z\;$ is the coset of $\;z\in\Bbb Z_3[x]\;$ in the quotient,

Comment: What are some of the ideals in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$ containing $(x^3 + x + 1). How would I go about finding them$?